# How can i get a content script to access chrome storage api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I’m new to this so excuse me.

Im storing values inside the chrome storage api using chrome.storage.local in one of my scripts that i run in the popup. how would i get my content script to pull that value from the chrome storage or is this just not possible.

for example:

> popup.js

```
chrome.storage.local.set({‘wins’:value})
```

> contentscript.js

```
chrome.storage.local.get([‘wins’], function(result) {
    numberwins = result.key
    console.log(‘You have ‘ + result.key); 
});
```

Comment: Replace both `result.key` with `result.wins`

Comment: thanks it now gets recognized in the logs! if i wanted to assign that value to a variable would i use stringify?

Comment: See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)